# Bind list to Cassandra WHERE clause: getting "Codec not found for requested operation: [list<varchar> <-> scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon]"

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax, cql

I am trying to bind a Scala List after the "IN" keyword in a CQL WHERE clause.

I tried this

```
val session: com.datastax.driver.core.Session = ...
val deleteStatement = session.prepare(s"DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN ?;")

def deleteById(ids: List[String]): Try[Boolean] = {
  val boundStatement = new BoundStatement(deleteStatement)
  boundStatement.bind(ids)
  session.execute(boundStatement).wasApplied()
}
```

But "boundStatement.bind" throws

> Codec not found for requested operation: [list <-> scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon]

How do I bind this list?

Answer (score 1):

Since the datastax library is written in Java, the BoundStatement is expecting a Java collection. You can explicitly convert your Scala collection to a Java collection like this:

```
boundStatement.bind(new java.util.ArrayList[String](ids.asJava))
```

Note that an implicit conversion does not work here, since the bind() method accepts parameters of type java.lang.Object rather than something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to do:

```
boundStatement.bind().setList(0, ids.asJava)
```

Or:

```
boundStatement.bind().setList(0, ids.asJava, classOf[String])
```